# I can not display ∫2xdx on my tkinter screen using python

Tags: python

I am working on `Tkinter` project to better myself in Python. I am trying to display mathematics symbols in my Tkinter screen like this:

```
∫2xdx
```

but I was not successful. I used :Sympy, init_printing(), but was not successful to print the integral like this. Any help?

Comment: what specific error are you getting?

Comment: There are not errors, but I do not like the way it displays on the screen. for instance: I am trying to factorize the expression: x**2 - 2*x +1 and the answer I am getting is: (x-1)**2, but I do not want that display, I want that nice and readable display:(x-1),exp(2) at the top . Same as the display for the integral nice and readable.

Answer (score 0):

To print out special characters, declare encoding at the top of your `.py` file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
print('∫2xdx') # output: ∫2xdx
```

Comment: Glad I could help! If this was satisfactory, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)